# Angular 2 500 Internal Server for URL: api/edit at new Error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

Hello I am getting this error when attempting to build. The routing is based off the Angular Heroes tutorial here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

However when I run I get this error:

**Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL: api/edit
at new Error (native)**

neuralnet.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import * as App from './neuralnet';

@Injectable()
export class NeuralNetService {

    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    private editUrl = 'api/edit';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getNets(): Promise<App.NeuralNet[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.editUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as App.NeuralNet[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
}}
```

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks

Comment: I believe the problem relates to not having a systemjs-angular-loader.js file. Instead I need to integrate with MVC